# Redirect all files in folder to another folder - keep queries intact

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mod-alias

I'm trying to redirect all files within a folder to another folder using htaccess.  Each file may or may not have a query string. And that query string may vary.

Example:

- http://www.example.com/articles/1234/title-of-article?nopaging=1

should redirect to:

- http://www.example.com/article/1234/title-of-article?nopaging=1

(The folder names "articles" plural became "article" singular.)

This seems a rather simple thing to do without the query string 
for example

```
 RewriteRule ^articles/(.*)$ /article/$1 [L,NC]
```

... but apparently I must use "rewritecond" when dealing with query strings and I can't find any online example of how to forward from one folder to another while keeping any/all query strings intact.

I think that there needs to be a condition matching any and all query strings, eg:

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
```

... but then it falls apart, because this certainly doesn't work:

```
 RewriteRule ^$ www.example.com/articles/$1 [QSA,R,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following Redirect :

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/articles/(.+)$ /article/$1
```

Comment: That works great, thanks!  I made it a 301 'cause it's a permanent redirect from outdated pages and it still works just fine.  Thanks again.

Comment: Ditto. I made it 301 but works perfect. Nice. Thanks!!